# Bootstrap child div height inside parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Working fine:
[image: Everything fine here]

Looks clear, nothing goes over parent div.
But once i fill it with some content it expands:
[image: Expanded]

```html
<div class="d-flex mx-5 my-4 h-75">
    <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column" style="margin-right: 15px">
      <!-- SEARCH -->
      <div class="d-flex">
        <card-search />
      </div>
      <!-- OTHER -->
      <div
        class="d-flex justify-content-between h-100"
        style="margin-top: 10px; max-height: 100%"
      >
        <!-- FILTER -->
        <div class="" style="margin-right: 15px">
          <card-filter />
        </div>
        <!-- CATALOGUE -->
        <div class="flex-fill">
          <card-catalogue />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <div class="w-50">
      <card-information />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried h-100 on the right DIV?

Comment: @EduDev yes, nothing changes.

Comment: What about the `margin-top: 10px`? Inline-style overrides your h-100 class, not sure whether the max-height: 100% works fine then. Did you try checking it with the dev-tools (right click -> 'untersuchen') of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try too add h-100 class hope that work for you and remove max-height: 100%


<div class="d-flex mx-5 my-4 h-75">
<div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column h-100" style="margin-right: 15px">
  <!-- SEARCH -->
  <div class="d-flex">
    <card-search />
  </div>
  <!-- OTHER -->
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between h-100" style="margin-top: 10px;>
    <!-- FILTER -->
    <div class="" style="margin-right: 15px">
      <card-filter />
    </div>
    <!-- CATALOGUE -->
    <div class="flex-fill">
      <card-catalogue />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- RIGHT -->
<div class="w-50 h-100">
  <card-information />
</div>
```